# Creating an MVC ActionResult that will take a list of files, zip them up and serve them back to the user

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, zip

I have found some code that does this using a 3rd party DLL, but I want to be able to do this using the native .net ZipArchive. The code I have so far is:

```
public class ZipResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> files;
    private string fileName;

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return fileName ?? "Logfiles.zip";
        }
        set { fileName = value; }
    }

    public ZipResult(params string[] files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public ZipResult(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var entry = zip.CreateEntry("test.txt");
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(
                        "Etiam eros nunc, hendrerit nec malesuada vitae, pretium at ligula.");
                }
            }

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

            zipStream.Position = 0;

            zipStream.CopyTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but obviously does not actually add any existing files to the archive, it simply creates a new text file and adds that. What I want is the ability to pass in a list of files and have them all added to the archive before it is sent back to the user. Here is what I have done to try and make this work.

```
public class ZipResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> files;
    private string fileName;

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return fileName ?? "Logfiles.zip";
        }
        set { fileName = value; }
    }

    public ZipResult(params string[] files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public ZipResult(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file);

                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
                            fileStream.Flush();
                            fileStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
      }

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

            zipStream.Position = 0;

            zipStream.CopyTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work. It doesn't even add a single file to the archive. I am obviously missing something really obvious, but I am suffering from code blindness.

All advice and help much appreciated.

Cheers Mike

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. The main issue with the original code was that CreateEntry was being given the entire path and not just a filename and it was actually silently failing to create the entry!!!

Once I fixed that I also found that there are some nice extension methods in the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly that do all this for me. So here is the final code.

```
public class ZipResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> files;
    private string zipFileName;

    public string ZipFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return zipFileName ?? "Logfiles.zip";
        }
        set { zipFileName = value; }
    }

    public ZipResult(params string[] files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public ZipResult(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

                    zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

            context.HttpContext
                .Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ZipFileName);

            zipStream.Position = 0;

            zipStream.CopyTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers Mike